# SendMessage {ENTER} to Internet Explorer browser iFrame element

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, winapi, iframe, sendmessage

I have a little project that needs me to automate IE.
I've used `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` class for the initial move. (attaching to IE)

But after that I want to use the Windows API to get focus to browser element and to click it.

I know that I can do this job more easy with the built in function of `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`, or use 3rd party class like **Watin**

But this time I want to use Windows API.

This is work perfect when I open IE browser and find some links/element to click

I used the key press {TAB} to iterate thru HTML elements then read the IE status bar to get its link. Then I use the key press `{ENTER}` to click/execute it.

I got problem when the element that are selected by {TAB} are inside iFrame, the keypress {ENTER} not work.

Here is my sample code

```vb
Imports WindowsApplication1.win_Api
Module browser
    Public Class IE
        Private Shared IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        Sub New(Optional ByVal url As String = "about:blank")
            Dim bw As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
            IE = bw
            Try
                IE.Navigate(url)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
        Shared Sub click(byval url as string)
            Dim Z As Integer = 0
            Do While Z = 0
                IE.Stop()
                'Send keboard press TAB this API is work perfect
                SendMessage(IE.HWND, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, Keys.Tab, 0)
                IE.Stop()
                If IE.StatusText = url Then
                    Z = 1
                End If
            Loop
            For Each I As IntPtr In GetChildWindows(IE.HWND)
                Dim L As Integer = 256
                Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(L)
                GetClassName(I, sb, L)
                If sb.ToString = "Internet Explorer_Server" Then
                    'Send keyboard press ENTER, this work
                    'But not work if the element selected by TAB action is on iframe
                    SendMessage(I, WM_CHAR, Keys.Enter, 0)
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Use the `ShDocVw` interface, You already have the URL, just call `Navigate`.  Reading the status bar is not really going to be all that stable. What if the user is browsing in a small window, and the URL is truncated? Sending virtual key presses is problematic too.  What if the user presses tab themselves?

Comment: SendMessage(WM_CHAR) [doesn't work in general](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/28/10190521.aspx).  Use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: I can get it with `Navigate` method, but i need to do this job with api (i think `Navigate` method is part of dom method, i used it to open homepage only). `SendInput` work, but require me to focus on IE. `SendMessage` work only to non iframe element. :/. I tryng to make project to automate IE with less DOM used.